# How to plot maps scattered over another plot (i.e. outside their actual coordinates)?

Tags: r, rgdal

I want to print a table of maps: one small map on each cell. How do I do that with `rgdal`?

There's other data on the table, so the maps must be added over it.

I've tried with `layout`, but it doesn't seem to work well with `par(new=T)`:

```
# adds the first data to the table
layout(matrix(1:4,2,2))
for (i in 1:4) {
  plot(NA,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,1))
  text(.5,.5,i,cex=5,pos=4)
}

# Tries to add the second data (text here for simplicity, maps on the original)
par(new=T,bg=rgb(0,0,0,0))
layout(matrix(1:4,2,2))
for (i in 1:4) {
  plot(NA,xlim=c(0,3),ylim=c(0,3))
  text(1.5,1.5,i,cex=5,col='green',pos=2)
}
```

This should create a new, transparent, plot area over the previous one, but the last plot commands are erasing the first one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you not plot your maps first and then add whatever you need on top with commands that do not create new plots (*e.g.* `points()` or `lines()` )?

Comment: @RomainB. I guess so.